# Como somar TIME em SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho essa consulta abaixo e gostaria de somar o total de horas/minutos agrupados por mês.

```
SELECT distinct
a.NUM_PROCES AS PROCESSO,
dpto,
data_rea,
total_he
FROM DOCUMENTO AS DOCUMENTO
INNER JOIN PROCES_WORKFLOW AS A ON DOCUMENTO.NR_DOCUMENTO = A.NR_DOCUMENTO_CARD
INNER JOIN ML001007 AS b ON DOCUMENTO.NR_DOCUMENTO = b.documentid
INNER JOIN histor_proces AS histor_proces ON A.NUM_PROCES = histor_proces.NUM_PROCES
where DOCUMENTO.NR_VERSAO = b.version 
and VERSAO_ATIVA = '1'
GROUP BY a.NUM_PROCES, dpto,data_rea,total_he
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A sugestão inicial é converter as horas e minutos em minutos para somar

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19535718/sum-total-time-in-sql-server    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725732/how-to-sum-up-time-field-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o `select` abaixo, estava com a mesma necessidade e esse código resolveu na minha situação.

```
SELECT time_format( SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( total_he ) ) ),'%H:%i') 
AS total_horas FROM SUATABELA
```

Substitua onde está *SUATABELA*, pela nome da tabela de seu banco de dados

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).